# Bundling Cocoapod dependencies in Source Control on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, github, cocoapods

I am developing an application for someone and I want to use an open source library (AFNetworking). I use cocoapods to install all dependencies. My question is: how can I upload all the cocoapod dependenices on github when I finish the application? Is there a way to upload them so when he downloads the source code he can run them directly or must I ask him to install the AFNetworking library via cocoapods too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install all your Cocoapods dependencies using "pod install", it creates "Pods" folder in your directory where Podfile is located. This contains all the dependencies (Pods) required by your project. Apart from this "Podfile.lock" is also generated. Just check-in "Pods" and "Podfile.lock" along with your project and you are good to go. Client then don't need to do anything else.

Comment: yeah after asking on forums etc, I was told that there's no way to upload the files directly to github from cocoapods, so I just downloaded and copied the source files myself, but thanks anyway.